# how to disable other user to click/ edit on specific row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a data table in my project. And it will be view/access by many users at the same time.

But I want after one row is selected and edited by one user, this specific row needs to become unclickable to edit/update by other users who view the same page/datatable.
This row or button needs to become unclickable by others while there are users who currently edit the value of this specific row.

```
$('#example tr').click( function() { }
```

How can I do that. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: User input validation server side is your answer

Comment: What have you tried so far? What server side language are you using? Basically you have to save the currently edited row-id to the server, save it and let all clients poll the server for currently locked rows and disable the inputs. But without further info and no specific problem it's difficult to help.

Comment: This approach is going to open up a variety of other problems.  For example, how do you determine that a row should be *unlocked*?  What if a user clicks on a row and then walks away, or closes their browser, or their computer crashes in some way unrelated to what they're doing on your page?  Expect to get *a lot* of support calls asking you to administratively unlock a row that was accidentally locked.  And then how are you going to determine which of those support calls should be overridden and which shouldn't?  Whatever actual problem you're trying to solve, there's a better way.

Comment: @JakubLicznerski, may you elaborate it ?, sorry im still beginner on programming, so bear with me

Comment: @Andy i use php ajax

Comment: @David i planned to using button, so when update button clicked, there will be pop up window, it also change flag value to 1,and that will triggered unclickable function on that specific row. When pop up window not currently open the flag value will be back 0, but i still dont really know how to implement it

Comment: @dimass.: Overall this is too broad to be answered here.  You're somewhat vaguely describing some requirements, but what you need to do is attempt to implement the actual functionality.  Just take it one piece at a time.  If you try to implement a single piece of the functionality you want, where do you get stuck?  As for the functionality yourself, I'm just letting you know that it *will* cause other problems you haven't thought of yet.  This isn't the first time something like this has been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do it via js on FE side. you should have BE solution for this, in order to block or do some other actions. you can use something like firebase ...